# Accessing self-type fields with a trait reference

Tags: scala

If I have a trait with a structural self type

```
sealed trait UserView { self: {val userWrapper: UserWrapper} =>
....
}
```

and an object `uv` of  type `UserView`, why doesn't `uv.userWrapper` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, where is self visible? Right, just inside the definition of your trait or the object extending it. It is just a condition that any instance has to satisfy, but it does not have any effect on the type UserView itself. Why would it? It is just a constraint on the type for the self-reference.

Self-types are useful to declare such constraints without putting it in the interface of a type. So you can declare that your trait requires some interface when it is mixed in.

If you want all instances to have a certain field, why not just use an abstract definition:

```
sealed trait UserView {
  def userWrapper: UserWrapper
}
```

You can implement that using a def or a val.